# How to fix couln't load image when applying merged-images in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `base64 image` here and already converted.

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

and every time I try to apply on `merge-images` always get this error:

`core.mjs:6494 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Couldn't load image`

here's the code:

```
const mergedImage = await mergeImages([base64]);
console.log(mergedImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is within `mergeImages` function.
It has to return a Promise (it is an async function).
You just have a base64, so you just need to insert this encode on `src` of a tag `img`.

What does the function does?